# How to redirect all routes to gatsby index

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, reach-router

I'm trying to make a Gatsby project that has only one page to handle all the routes. I have am index page like this:

```
const App = () => {
  return <Router>
    <Home path="/"/>
    <Login path="/login" />
    <Content path="/content" />
  </Router>
}
```

on `src/pages` folder I have only `index.js`

How can I make this page handle all the routes?

Checking Gatsby docs (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/) I know that I can use the plugin `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths` like this:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`,
  options: { prefixes: [`/app/*`] },
},
```

This works well if I make a page called `app.js` using a react router. So all the routes `/app/*` goes to this page.

But how can I make this kind of redirect on the root url: `/`. I want to make that any route `/*` goes to the index page: `index.js`

Any suggestions on how to do this? :)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: not yet Simon. I'm using a plugin called `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`. It works well for custom prefixed routes like `/app` but I wasn't able to make it work on the root route `/`

Answer (score 3):

Setup `index.js` like this:

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Home path="/"/>
      <Login path="/login" />
      <Content path="/content" />
    </Router>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

and in `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  if (page.path === `/`) {
    page.matchPath = `/*`
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

Restart `gatsby develop` and the index page will handle the routes you've setup.

Comment: Not sure if Filipe has seen this answer, but it worked for me. I was also using the same plugin.