# Gatsby + Reach router: best pattern for controlling client route paths

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby, reach-router

My goal is to enable the following types of static and dynamic paths with the best pattern possible when using Gatsby (v2) and @reach/router. The problem I've run into is that the Gatsby docs set you up to prefix the path `/app` on every dynamic route, which does not fit my use case.

Desired paths:

- `/`: static route and build-time generated
- `/about`: static route and build-time generated
- `/:username`: dynamic route and run-time generated
- `/:username/:postTitleSlug`: dynamic route and run-time generated

Following the Gatsby docs, I have this folder structure:

```
/pages
  index.jsx
  about.jsx
  app.jsx
/templates
  profile.jsx // for the /:username path
  post.jsx // for the /:username/:postTitleSlug path
```

**app.jsx**

```
const Routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <Profile path="/:username" />
    <Read path="/:username/:slug" />
  </Router>
);
```

**gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  if (page.path.match(/^\/app/)) {
    await createPage({
      path: 'app',
      matchPath: '/app/*',
      component: path.resolve('src/templates/Profile/index.js'),
    });
  }
};
```

Is it possible to unwind the "app" nomenclature and key some dynamic routes off of the base path, `/`?

FWIW, my first attempted fix was to make `pages/index.jsx` just a router, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63771163/how-to-redirect-all-routes-to-gatsby-index). It seems like a potential solution, but I'm not clear on the required updates to `gatsby-node.js`.

Answer (score 1):

- For your `/` just create an index.js file inside your `/pages` folder, Gatsby will take it as a home page by default.
- For your /about page, just create an `about.js` inside your /pages folder. Since Gatsby is a file-path based it will take it to build your `/about` page. The same approach works for all static pages.

For the [client-only routes](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/), the "first" slug (`:username`) needs to be handled by Gatsby in order to avoid a 404 error, while the second (`:slug`) can be handled by the `@reach/router`. Something like:

```
// Implement the Gatsby API “onCreatePage”. This is
// called after every page is created.
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
  // only on the client.
  if (page.path.match(/^\/user\/$/)) {
    createPage({
      ...page,
      matchPath: '/:username/*'
    })
  }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
 <Router>
        <User path="/user/:username" />
        <UserAsset path="/user/:username/:slug" />
 </Router>
```

This approach handles `/user/:username/:slug` but you can adapt it to your needs.

Alternatively, you can save this workaround by using [`gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths/) plugin simply by:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`,
  options: { prefixes: [`/username/*`] },
},
```